"Many English words ARE derived from French." VS "Many English words WERE derived from French."
In my native language, the translation of the following a- and b-variants has the same meaning.
Tell me please whether they have difference in English or not.
britannica.com:
(1a) Many English words are derived from French.
(2a) The river derives its name from a Native American tribe.
vocabulary.com:
(3a) The present name derives from an older form.
my variants:
(1b) Many English words were derived from French.
(2b) The river derived its name from a Native American tribe.
(3b) The present name derived from an older form.
Is there any difference between the a- and b-variants?

If the words or names are used now in the present then they have current existence and we use the present tense about them. Your 'variants' are unnecessary.

Most people would understand, however changing it to past tense could imply that might no longer be the case - and adds ambiguity. "Many English words were derived from French, but are now derived from Spanish"

You should be able to validate your variants by using Google books, Ngrams, and dictionaries. Do you find any examples of "word was derived from"?

Read the examples from the link, and see if there is a strong reason for using the past simple passive.

@Mari-LouA You wrote "You should be able to...". But I have no such ability which you seem to think I have. I can't answer this question by myself. Those sources you mentioned are not enough for me to understand it. Do you think I should not have asked it?

The door is painted blue. The door was painted blue.  They can have the same meaning in context but don't necessarily have the same meaning. The door could be red now. With the past tense were derived you could be speaking of French loan-words no longer in use, as about 25% of them are not. It depends on what you mean by "English words", and the past-tense begs that question.

I think you do have this ability, but maybe you just don't want to put in the effort? It's quicker if someone posts an answer, but more often than not, you challenge that answer, refusing to take it at its face value. Googling is the minimal means of  research. I gave you a link  which contains the phrase "word was derived" in published texts. Why shouldn't that resource help you reach a better-informed understanding?  You could even quote one or two examples and ask "why" in those cases the past passive was chosen.

@Mari-LouA 1) You wrote: "You could even quote one or two examples and ask "why" in those cases the past passive was chosen.". I'm interested in those examples I wrote in the original post, not in others. If you continue to think that after I go over your link, I can deal with them on my own, okay. 2) You wrote: "if someone posts an answer, but more often than not, you challenge that answer, refusing to take it at its face value". I don't know why you think so. I can only ask when I don't understand. If you perceived something as challenging, let me assure you I never had such a purpose.

You often challenge answers–not always a bad thing–when you comment on them and list a third, a fourth, or even a fifth example that you believe is correct when very often it is not.

When you receive seven answers that tell you "Man" means mankind and does not require the definite article, you stubbornly ask why the opposite is not also true.

@Mari-LouA, Loviii: The Google Books search for word was derived from shows me at least 10 pages with 10 results per page, which is exactly the same as I get after changing the search term to  word is derived from (because initially Google Books only reports up to 100 results). A much clearer indication of relative prevalence can be obtained from an NGram chart. There's little room for doubt after looking at that!

@Mari-LouA "a third" - I didn't understand why I can't use "ingredients" without "the". That's why I continued asking questions about this. At this moment I still don't fully know it. "a fifth example" - I asked the question which I didn't understand. After those questions I finally understood it.

@Mari-LouA "stubbornly" - I tried to understand your beginning of the answer: "The man hunted, gathered wild berries, and fended for himself. - This refers to a nameless male individual." At this moment I still don't understand it.

@Mari-LouA why the opposite - I asked that because at that moment I didn't understand that. And I managed to understand only after I began asking that.

What you are saying is all the answers that were posted did not fully convince you. You can't expect me to believe you didn't understand, you understood something but it didn't totally clear up your confusion. And now, this is my last interaction. I have stuff to do!

EDIT: I'll explain it now, and if you want to reply then post a comment under the answer: A nameless man, means a man, a person who has not been named in the text. It is an example of using "the" with the singular meaning of "man". Now post your comment challenging the meaning underneath my answer :P

EDIT: @FumbleFingers It's not only the number of hits that counts, it's also the context in which they are used.

Your native language makes no distinction between present and past tense?

Yes, they do "have difference" inasmuch as the present tense version cannot be used in every context that the past tense version can, and vice versa.
The overwhelming majority of French words that were incorporated into English entered the language over the course of the Middle English period.
This sentence is OK:

Approximately 75% of the English words that were derived from French are still in use today.

But this sentence is  somewhat confusing with the present-tense "are derived":

Approximately 25% of the English words that are derived from French are no longer in use today.

Of course one could construct a paragraph in which that sentence was not confusing, but having to do so amounts to a difference between the two constructions.

You wrote the following sentence is somewhat confusing: "Approximately 25% of the English words that are derived from French are no longer in use today." Am I right that it's confusing because you perceive "are derived" as passive? That is, the active would be "someone derives 25% of the English words from French nowadays" the meaning of which is really confusing in terms of the whole sentence. But what if you perceived "derived from French" as the adjectival phrase which would describe a property of the subject "approximately 25% of the English words"? Thanks.

@Lovii  No. The confusion stems from the choice of tense.   "English words that are derived from French" is followed by "are no longer in use".  If you're going to be talking about something that took place in the past followed by something that has happened over the course of centuries resulting in the current state of affairs, it would be clearer to use "were....are" not "are....are".
